# Error running pod install Error launching application on iPhone 11 Pro Max

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase, android-studio, dart

Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 11 Pro Max in debug mode...
Running pod install...
CocoaPods' output:
↳
Preparing

```
Analyzing dependencies

Inspecting targets to integrate
  Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (``)

Fetching external sources
-> Fetching podspec for `Flutter` from `Flutter`
-> Fetching podspec for `cloud_firestore` from `.symlinks/plugins/cloud_firestore/ios`
cloud_firestore: Using Firebase SDK version '8.10.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
-> Fetching podspec for `firebase_auth` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_auth/ios`
firebase_auth: Using Firebase SDK version '8.10.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
-> Fetching podspec for `firebase_core` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_core/ios`
firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '8.10.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
```

Error output from CocoaPods:
↳
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi/library.rb:275: [BUG] Bus Error at 0x0000000100994000
ruby 2.6.8p205 (2021-07-07 revision 67951) [universal.arm64e-darwin21]

```
-- Crash Report log information --------------------------------------------
   See Crash Report log file under the one of following:
     * ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports
     * /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports
   for more details.
Don't forget to include the above Crash Report log file in bug reports.

-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0069 p:---- s:0424 e:000423 CFUNC  :attach
c:0068 p:0258 s:0418 e:000417 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi/library.rb:275
c:0067 p:0050 s:0398 e:000397 CLASS  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.14.0/lib/ethon/libc.rb:17
c:0066 p:0007 s:0395 e:000394 CLASS  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.14.0/lib/ethon/libc.rb:7
c:0065 p:0007 s:0392 e:000391 TOP    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.14.0/lib/ethon/libc.rb:2 [FINISH]
c:0064 p:---- s:0389 e:000388 CFUNC  :require
c:0063 p:0110 s:0384 e:000383 METHOD /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54
c:0062 p:0042 s:0372 e:000371 TOP    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.14.0/lib/ethon.rb:15 [FINISH]
c:0061 p:---- s:0369 e:000368 CFUNC  :require
c:0060 p:0110 s:0364 e:000363 METHOD /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54
c:0059 p:0013 s:0352 e:000351 TOP    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/typhoeus-1.4.0/lib/typhoeus.rb:2 [FINISH]
c:0058 p:---- s:0349 e:000348 CFUNC  :require
c:0057 p:0110 s:0344 e:000343 METHOD /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54
c:0056 p:0006 s:0332 e:000331 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:440
c:0055 p:0045 s:0324 e:000323 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:372
c:0054 p:0318 s:0313 e:000312 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:365
c:0053 p:0065 s:0303 e:000301 BLOCK  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:131 [FINISH]
c:0052 p:---- s:0297 e:000296 CFUNC  :map
c:0051 p:0036 s:0293 e:000290 BLOCK  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:124
c:0050 p:0002 s:0287 e:000286 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:479
c:0049 p:0104 s:0281 e:000280 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:121
c:0048 p:0015 s:0273 e:000269 BLOCK  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/specification/set.rb:99 [FINISH]
c:0047 p:---- s:0265 e:000264 IFUNC 
c:0046 p:---- s:0262 e:000261 CFUNC  :each
c:0045 p:---- s:0259 e:000258 CFUNC  :each_with_object
c:0044 p:0024 s:0254 e:000253 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/specification/set.rb:98
c:0043 p:0004 s:0250 e:000249 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/specification/set.rb:56
c:0042 p:0126 s:0246 e:000245 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:216
c:0041 p:0008 s:0237 e:000236 BLOCK  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/source/aggregate.rb:83 [FINISH]
c:0040 p:---- s:0233 e:000232 CFUNC  :select
c:0039 p:0008 s:0229 e:000228 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/source/aggregate.rb:83
c:0038 p:0011 s:0223 e:000222 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:416
c:0037 p:0101 s:0218 e:000214 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:385
c:0036 p:0051 s:0207 e:000206 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:360
c:0035 p:0060 s:0199 e:000195 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:165
c:0034 p:0066 s:0189 e:000184 BLOCK  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:274 [FINISH]
c:0033 p:---- s:0180 e:000179 IFUNC 
c:0032 p:---- s:0177 e:000176 IFUNC 
c:0031 p:---- s:0174 e:000173 CFUNC  :each
c:0030 p:---- s:0171 e:000170 CFUNC  :sort_by
c:0029 p:---- s:0168 e:000167 CFUNC  :sort_by!
c:0028 p:0006 s:0164 e:000163 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:267
c:0027 p:0014 s:0157 e:000156 BLOCK  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/delegates/specification_provider.rb:60
c:0026 p:0002 s:0154 e:000153 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/delegates/specification_provider.rb:77
c:0025 p:0005 s:0148 e:000147 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/delegates/specification_provider.rb:59
c:0024 p:0029 s:0141 e:000140 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:754
c:0023 p:0051 s:0131 e:000130 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:744
c:0022 p:0047 s:0125 e:000124 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:727
c:0021 p:0114 s:0121 e:000120 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:684
c:0020 p:0010 s:0115 e:000114 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:254
c:0019 p:0082 s:0110 e:000109 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:182
c:0018 p:0037 s:0106 e:000105 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolver.rb:43
c:0017 p:0049 s:0100 e:000099 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:94
c:0016 p:0041 s:0094 e:000093 BLOCK  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1078
c:0015 p:0081 s:0090 e:000089 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64
c:0014 p:0078 s:0083 e:000082 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1076
c:0013 p:0161 s:0076 e:000075 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:124
c:0012 p:0011 s:0061 e:000060 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:416
c:0011 p:0007 s:0056 e:000055 BLOCK  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:241
c:0010 p:0081 s:0053 e:000052 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64
c:0009 p:0048 s:0046 e:000045 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:240
c:0008 p:0009 s:0040 e:000039 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:161
c:0007 p:0054 s:0036 e:000035 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52
c:0006 p:0078 s:0031 e:000030 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334
c:0005 p:0024 s:0024 e:000023 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52
c:0004 p:0378 s:0019 e:000018 TOP    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/bin/pod:55 [FINISH]
c:0003 p:---- s:0013 e:000012 CFUNC  :load
c:0002 p:0109 s:0008 E:000400 EVAL   /usr/local/bin/pod:23 [FINISH]
c:0001 p:0000 s:0003 E:0011d0 (none) [FINISH]

-- Ruby level backtrace information ----------------------------------------
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:161:in `install!'
```

core/cdn_source.rb:124:in `block in versions' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:124:in` map'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in versions'` attach_function'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi/library.rb:275:in `attach'

```
-- Other runtime information -----------------------------------------------

* Loaded script: /usr/local/bin/pod

* Loaded features:

    0 enumerator.so
    1 thread.rb
    2 rational.so
    3 complex.so
    4 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/universal-darwin21/enc/encdb.bundle
    5 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/universal-darwin21/enc/trans/transdb.bundle
    6 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/universal-darwin21/rbconfig.rb
    7 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/compatibility.rb
    8 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/defaults.rb
    9 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/deprecate.rb
   10 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/errors.rb
   11 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/version.rb
   12 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/requirement.rb
   13 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/platform.rb
   14 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/basic_specification.rb
   15 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/stub_specification.rb
   16 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/delegate.rb
   17 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/uri/rfc2396_parser.rb
   18 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/uri/rfc3986_parser.rb
   19 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/uri/common.rb
   20 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/uri/generic.rb
   21 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/uri/file.rb
   22 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/uri/ftp.rb
   23 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/uri/http.rb
   24 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/uri/https.rb
   25 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/uri/ldap.rb
   26 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/uri/ldaps.rb
   27 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/uri/mailto.rb
   28 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/uri.rb
   29 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification_policy.rb
   30 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/util/list.rb
   31 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/universal-darwin21/stringio.bundle
   32 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb
   33 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/exceptions.rb
   34 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/util.rb
   35 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/bundler_version_finder.rb
   36 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/dependency.rb
   37 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb
   38 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/monitor.rb
   39 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb
   40 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_warn.rb
   41 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb
   42 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/path_support.rb
   43 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/did_you_mean-1.3.0/lib/did_you_mean/version.rb
   44 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/did_you_mean-1.3.0/lib/did_you_mean/core_ext/name_error.rb
   45 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/did_you_mean-1.3.0/lib/did_you_mean/levenshtein.rb
   46 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/did_you_mean-1.3.0/lib/did_you_mean/jaro_winkler.rb
   47 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/did_you_mean-1.3.0/lib/did_you_mean/spell_checker.rb
   48 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/did_you_mean-1.3.0/lib/did_you_mean/spell_checkers/name_error_checkers/class_name_checker.rb
   49 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/did_you_mean-1.3.0/lib/did_you_mean/spell_checkers/name_error_checkers/variable_name_checker.rb
   50 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/did_you_mean-1.3.0/lib/did_you_mean/spell_checkers/name_error_checkers.rb
   51 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/did_you_mean-1.3.0/lib/did_you_mean/spell_checkers/method_name_checker.rb
   52 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/did_you_mean-1.3.0/lib/did_you_mean/spell_checkers/key_error_checker.rb
   53 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/did_you_mean-1.3.0/lib/did_you_mean/spell_checkers/null_checker.rb
   54 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/did_you_mean-1.3.0/lib/did_you_mean/formatters/plain_formatter.rb
   55 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/did_you_mean-1.3.0/lib/did_you_mean.rb
   56 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb
   57 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/request_set/gem_dependency_api.rb
   58 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/request_set/lockfile/parser.rb
   59 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/request_set/lockfile/tokenizer.rb
   60 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/request_set/lockfile.rb
   61 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/request_set.rb
   62 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/gem_metadata.rb
   63 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/errors.rb
   64 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/set.rb
   65 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/dependency_graph/action.rb
   66 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/dependency_graph/add_edge_no_circular.rb
   67 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/dependency_graph/add_vertex.rb
   68 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/dependency_graph/delete_edge.rb
   69 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/dependency_graph/detach_vertex_named.rb
   70 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/dependency_graph/set_payload.rb
   71 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/dependency_graph/tag.rb
   72 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/dependency_graph/log.rb
   73 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/dependency_graph/vertex.rb
   74 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/dependency_graph.rb
   75 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/state.rb
   76 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/modules/specification_provider.rb
   77 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/delegates/resolution_state.rb
   78 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/delegates/specification_provider.rb
   79 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb
   80 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/resolver.rb
   81 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/modules/ui.rb
   82 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo.rb
   83 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo.rb
   84 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/resolver/activation_request.rb
   85 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/resolver/conflict.rb
   86 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/resolver/dependency_request.rb
   87 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/resolver/requirement_list.rb
   88 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/resolver/stats.rb
   89 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/resolver/set.rb
   90 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/resolver/api_set.rb
   91 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/resolver/composed_set.rb
   92 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/resolver/best_set.rb
   93 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/resolver/current_set.rb
   94 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/resolver/git_set.rb
   95 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/resolver/index_set.rb
   96 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/resolver/installer_set.rb
   97 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/resolver/lock_set.rb
   98 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/resolver/vendor_set.rb
   99 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/resolver/source_set.rb
  100 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/resolver/specification.rb
  101 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/resolver/spec_specification.rb
  102 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/resolver/api_specification.rb
  103 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/resolver/git_specification.rb
  104 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/resolver/index_specification.rb
  105 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/resolver/installed_specification.rb
  106 
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/public_suffix-4.0.6/lib/public_suffix/version.rb
  284 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/public_suffix-4.0.6/lib/public_suffix/errors.rb
  285 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/public_suffix-4.0.6/lib/public_suffix/rule.rb
  286 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/public_suffix-4.0.6/lib/public_suffix/list.rb
  287 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/public_suffix-4.0.6/lib/public_suffix.rb
  288 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/addressable-2.8.0/lib/addressable/uri.rb
  289 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/addressable-2.8.0/lib/addressable/template.rb
  290 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/addressable-2.8.0/lib/addressable.rb
  291 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/inspector_reporter.rb
  292 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/core_ui.rb
  293 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb
  294 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/source/acceptor.rb
  295 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/source/aggregate.rb
 
  355 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/psych/json/tree_builder.rb
  356 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/psych/json/stream.rb
  357 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/psych/handlers/document_stream.rb
  358 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/psych.rb
  359 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/yaml.rb
  360 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/executable.rb
  361 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/version.rb
  362 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/errors.rb
  363 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/atomic/event.rb
  364 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/concern/dereferenceable.rb
  365 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/concern/obligation.rb
  366 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/logger.rb
  367 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/concern/logging.rb
  368 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/concern/deprecation.rb
  369 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/executor_service.rb
  370 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/abstract_executor_service.rb
  371 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/dataflow.rb
  434 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/maybe.rb
  435 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/exchanger.rb
  436 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/synchronization/abstract_struct.rb
  437 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/immutable_struct.rb
  438 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/mutable_struct.rb
  439 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/mvar.rb
  440 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/promise.rb
  441 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/settable_struct.rb

  664 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi/callback.rb
  665 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi/io.rb
  666 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi/autopointer.rb
  667 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi/variadic.rb
  668 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi/enum.rb
  669 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi/version.rb
  670 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi/ffi.rb
  671 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi.rb

[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: https://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html

[IMPORTANT]
Don't forget to include the Crash Report log file under
DiagnosticReports directory in bug reports.
```

Error: To set up CocoaPods for ARM macOS, run:
arch -x86_64 sudo gem install ffi

Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 11 Pro Max.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and this helped

```
sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi
cd ios/App
arch -x86_64 pod repo update
arch -x86_64 pod install
```